# add conditional character every i-th place in a string

Tags: javascript, loops, recursion

I want to write a function where given an index it adds a `<br>` tag at every Ith index in string. If the index is a space we will insert a `<br>`, but if it's in the middle of a string we insert `-<br>`

I saw a lot of examples using a combination of regex and joins, but I wasnt sure how to do this since my join would be conditional.

For Example:

```
let my_string = "Here's a really really long string that I want to add breaks to at every 20th interval"
```

I'd like my function insert_break(my_string, 20) to return

```
Here's a really reall-<br>y long string that I<br> want to add breaks <br>to at every 20th interval
```

So far my function works at the first specified index, but I wasnt sure if I should write a loop or recursive function in order to get this to work at every `index` interval in the string (in the example at `[20,60,40]` and right now it just works at `20`

Any help with the function appreciated:

```
insert_break = (str, index) => {
  
  // mostly we'll need to hyphenate the new line 
  let breakword = "-<br>"
  
  // but if there's a space before the index we dont
  if (str[index] === " ") { breakword = "<br>" }

  // I want this to run at every multiple of 20 within the string
  // so I need some kind of for loop (or something recursive?) 
  // to add a <br> at every multiple of the index
  if (index > 0) {

    // this works if we only want to run this function ONCE at the index 20
    //return str.substring(0, index) + breakword + str.substring(index)

    let breakstring = str
    for (let i = 1; i < Math.floor(str.length/index); i++) {
      // 1*20, 2*20, 3*20
      let idx = index*i

      // this doesnt work.
      // I need to add it to the new string, not write over the old one as I am here 
      breakstring = breakstring.substring(0, idx) + breakword + breakstring.substring(idx)
    }

    return breakstring
    //return str.substring(0, index) + breakword + str.substring(index)
  }

  return breakword + str
  
}
```

Any help appreciated!

Comment: You need to set `breakword` in the loop, since it can be different for each repetition.

Comment: The first break in your sample result is at index 21, not 20.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Loop over the string indexes in steps of `index`. Use `substring()` to extract each chunk of characters from the string, check its last character, and then append the appropriate form of `<br>`.

```js
function insert_break(str, index) {
  let result = "";
  for (let i = 0; i < str.length; i += index) {
    let chunk = str.substring(i, i + index);
    if (chunk.endsWith(' ')) {
      chunk += '<br>';
    } else {
      chunk += '-<br>';
    }
    result += chunk;
  }
  result = result.replace(/-?<br>$/, ''); // remove last `<br>`
  return result;
}

let my_string = "Here's a really really long string that I want to add breaks to at every 20th interval";
console.log(insert_break(my_string, 20));
```

Indexes start at 0, not 1, so you need to use that as the initial value of `i`.

Comment: This is amazing @Barmar but is it possible to remove the last `-<br>` as in your result `Here's a really real-<br>ly long string that <br>I want to add breaks-<br> to at every 20th in-<br>terval-<br>` ?

Comment: Maybe some logic not to add result to the last chunk?

Comment: I ended up adding `return result.slice(0, result.length - 5)` to account for the last `-<br>`;

Comment: You should check if the last one is `-<br>` or just `<br>` so you don't remove too much. You can use `result = result.replace(/-?<br>$/, '');`